# Adding dates to newly inserted rows weekly

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table that is updated weekly (on Monday) through a google sheet. The table name is weekly_volume.
contents of weekly_Volume :

| channel | Projected_rev | Sales_rev | Budget_revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 1814489386.0 | 121479385.0 | 11360045.0. |
| APAC | 8286784643.0 | 728478469.0 | 76538055.0. |

I want to use this table to create a new table (Weekly_volume_with_dates) and update it weekly which will add date fields as below whenever I run the date addition query.

for e.g if it is run today the table would look like this:-

| channel | Projected_rev | Sales_rev | Budget_revenue | Date | Yr | Mth | Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 1814489386.0 | 121479385.0 | 11360045.0. | 04-04-22 | 22 | 04 | aprwk1 |
| APAC | 8286784643.0 | 728478469.0 | 76538055.0. | 04-04-22 | 22 | 04 | aprwk1 |

If i run the process next week on 04-11-22 after new data is inserted in weekly_volume table it would look like this.

| channel | Projected_rev | Sales_rev | Budget_rev | Date | Yr | Mth | Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 4839959393.0 | 493483598.0 | 43489349.3 | 04-11-22 | 22 | 04 | aprwk2 |
| APAC | 8349320944.7 | 823049348.0 | 82043484.0 | 04-11-22 | 22 | 04 | aprwk2 |
| USA | 1814489386.0 | 121479385.0 | 11360045.0 | 04-04-22 | 22 | 04 | aprwk1 |
| APAC | 8286784643.0 | 728478469.0 | 76538055.0 | 04-04-22 | 22 | 04 | aprwk1 |

and so forth for every week i run the date addition script.
I am using BigQuery platform.

Comment: What is your question? So far it seems you want someone else do your work for you. Please show what you have tried or investigated.

Comment: In addition it is very suspicious your asking the same question (when I say the same I mean exactly) as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71714265/how-to-insert-created-date-weekly-to-newly-inserted-row so for me you created a new user to ask the same question or maybe we are in the multiverse

Comment: I created a new question as I could not create a new question from my previous account. I have tried using trigger but gcp does not support trigger. I tried using a create table into a new table but since I will create it every week the data will get overwritten. I don't want a written code just a hint or a new perspective to how this can be handled, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a longer approach it works for now.
inserted the weekly_Volume table date into a new table

```
insert into Weekly_volume_with_dates (channel, projected_rev,sales_rev, budget_revenue,month_date)
select channel, projected_rev,sales_rev, budget_revenue,null as month_date
from weekly_Volume
```

updated dates with null value with current date.

```
update Weekly_volume_with_dates
set month_date = current_date()
where month_date is null
```

created a new table using CTE and partitioning using row_number() function
so I could eliminate duplicate values that were written during the insert.

```
create or replace table rev_with_dates
as
with cte as
(
select channel, projected_rev ,sales_rev, budget_revenue ,month_date,
       row_number() over (partition by channel, projected_rev ,sales_rev, budget_revenue ,month_date order by month_Date) as rn
from Weekly_volume_with_dates
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
order by month_date desc
```

once I had distinct values for dates I used date functions to extract
week, month and year from the month_date field.

I am not quite sure if there is a chance that duplicates will still come thru.